# display input values after modal close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to do something like this. 

When the user clicked on the "+" icon, a form inside a modal will be shown.

[image: form image]

And when the user clicks the "add member" button, the modal will be closed and the input values entered by the user will be displayed just below the "+" icon. The problem is, when the user clicks the "+" icon again, the form will be shown, but when the "add member" button is clicked, the previous input values will be changed by the latest values entered by the user.

**"+" icon**

```
       <div class="form-group">
                 <span><b>Members:</b></span>
                 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberModal"><span class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></span></a>
                <div class="row" id="showaddedmember">
                     // DISPLAY ADDED MEMBER HERE
                </div>
       </div>
```

**Form code snippet**

```
       <div class="form-group row input_field">
                <label class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: right;">Firstname</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname[]" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row input_field">
                <label class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: right;">Middlename</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="middlename[]" placeholder="Middlename"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row input_field">
                <label class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: right;">Lastname</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname[]" placeholder="Lastname"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row input_field">
                <label class="col-lg-4" style="text-align: right;">Extension Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="extension_name[]" placeholder="Extension Name"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addmember_btn">Add Member</button>
           </div>
```

**When the "add member" button is clicked** (I only tried to display firstname)

```
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#addmember_btn', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

            var data = new Array();
            var content = "";

            var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;

             data[data.length] = fname;

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 content +=data[i]+"<br>";
             }

             document.getElementById('showaddedmember').innerHTML = content;

     });
```

I tried to console.log(data) and only the latest input values entered were stored in the data array. I am trying to do something like this, but my form should be in a modal. (http://jsfiddle.net/KsuxV/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
document.getElementById('showaddedmember').innerHTML = content;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('showaddedmember').innerHTML += content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using jQuery so, [use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/append). It will handle adding `content` to the inside but at the end of `showaddedmemeber`.

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '#addmember_btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new Array();
    var content = "";
    var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    data[data.length] = fname;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        content +=data[i]+"<br>";
    }

    $('#showaddedmember').append(content);

 });
```